# How to get rid of "Fancy vs Nasty" models/icons in Team Fortress 2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

When the ["Fancy vs Nasty"](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Fancy_vs._Nasty_Update) update went online I downloaded and installed nearly all of the models (weapons and hats) available. Now that ["Australian Christmas"](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Australian_Christmas) update brought most of the items into the game it's getting a little bit anoying. While examining backpack I see pretty much the same icon for axtinguisher and backscratcher, frying pan and equalizer and so on. There is no problem in the game itself, but I suspect that this is because most servers out there force only "pure" models. The files are probably still there. I deleted all game content and redownloaded it again, just to be sure, but to my surprise it didn't help.

So my question is: how to get rid of all the "Fancy vs Nasty" update models/icons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could delete it and then make sure you clean out the *Steam/steamapps/< yournick >/team fortress 2* folder.

However that would mean you'd have to redownload all of TF2, it's probably easier if you just redownload the Fancy vs. Nasty update, look inside it what files came with it and delete just those manually from above folder.
It's also probably a good idea to run "verify integrity of game cache" after that.

Comment: Sily me. I thought "delete all game content" meant deleting all game content. Naturally wiping out whole tf2 folder and re-downloading it fixed everything. Thanks.